# How to detect modification between 2 identical databases, database side?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, triggers, detection

here is my problem :

- I have a database (DataBase 1), it contains all initial data (DATA X). and can only be writen by an application. (SQL Server)
- I have a second database (DataBase 2), it cointains modified data (DATA y)
- The application is used to insert, modifiy and delete data in DataBase 1 . There is a script which detects changes and updates DataBase 2. But i dont have access to the source code of that script.

What i have to do is to detect changes on DataBase 1 (as the script does), store this information in another Database and then send notifications to users.

The problem is that i dont know how to detect these changes, if it was in a php routine i could have done it. Moreover i could duplicate tables and compare them but that is going to be too heavy.

Maybe there is a way to use listenners and triggers but i have not any ideas yet about that.

If anyone could help me for that, that would be great :)

---

this is an exemple of the output of what i have to do

> New Notification :
>
> > location has been changed from **x (data from database 1)** to **y (updated data)**

Comment: Do your tables have any fields that indicate when a field was created and last updated?

Comment: @DanBracuk : yes i do, i have a datetime field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are certain approaches to it.

Have trigger on your tables to log all the operations.

Use an identifer to find rows that are different then do whatever you opt to.

Use 3rd party tool like red gate data comparer that gives you script after comparison of all the configured tables.

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me. The first approach sounds interesting, Can you tell me a bit more about that please ? Does it mean that i have to create triggers on DB1, for every pertinent changes, which logs operations (including : old state of my data and new state with changes applied?) and then i update my database with new changes ? So i can retrieve data from logs, execute notification routine and clear logs ?  

Thanks for the tool, it's an interesting aswell !

Comment: You can create trigger on individual tables, then log the values and whenever you want to update refer id from table of database 1 and update or insert in table of database 2. This may be ok with database where there is limited amount of transaction, but as number of transaction grows you have to figure out ways to deal with it. Also check for replication and log shipping in sql that may help.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I actually have a big database to deal with and the service is provided to an important quantity of users. I have been asked to do that the most simple way possible. Okey i'll check that out :)

Comment: By the way i only have a reading only access to database 2. The only thing that can write there is the third party script which updates db2 from changes made on db1. It's a periodic update.